# Why are wait while-loop conditions safe in a multithreaded context?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have hard time to really understand, how that works:

```
while(<some condition>){
    wait();
}
OR this example:
while(<some condition>){
    condition.await();
}
```

When thread already passed the `<some condition>`,
it may really happen, that `<some condition>` already `false` when `wait()` or `await()` executed.

So `wait()` or `await()` may be called with already invalidated condition - that means the intention is broken.

What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: How would it be false? If it was already false, Java wouldn't even enter the while loop.

Comment: between condition check (suppose it is true) and calling wait() there is a time of uncertainty, where condition may be modified(set false). But wait will be called anyway.

Comment: @VladimirNabokov Until the thread calls `wait`, it holds the lock. The whole point of `wait` is to atomically release the lock and wait.

Comment: I think I missed important part: I need first acquire some lock(monitor), only with the same lock(monitor) another thread may modify condition. I missed a lock before while()!!!

Comment: Yes.  Silly Freak's answer implies (but does not come right out and say) that it's _up to you_ to insure that the condition is not true before you wait() for it.  `synchronized` blocks are the way to insure it.  The `foo.wait()` call is only allowed inside a `synchronized(foo)` block.  It's up to you to insure that any other fragment of code that can change the condition is also inside a `synchronized(foo)` block.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes. I got it. Usually following suggestion must follow: use actor pattern to avoid unnecessary lock issues. I would happily follow it, if I was 100% sure regarding internal implementation of that wonderful pattern in, say, wonderful AKKA framework. Some black-box feeling is keeping me from active usage of that technology in production. Really psychological issue. Some queues are too scary to use them blindly. OOM concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) for `wait()`:

> **The current thread must own this object's monitor.** The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.

(emphasis mine)

In other words, without a `synchronized` block, your code will throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException`. *With* `synchronized`, on the other hand, your condition will be checked atomically with the `wait();` call.

This does not automatically mean you have no problems, because "atomically" here is only with regard to the object you're synchronizing on (in your case `this`), and only relative to other synchronized access to that object. If your condition depends on different objects, or you access the object without synchronization somewhere else, things might go bad. Thus, don't do that.

---

The same reasoning goes for the use of `Lock`s and `Condition`s. [See this code sample.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) Condition variables are derived from lock objects, and `synchronized`/`wait`/`notify` is analogous to `lock`;`unlock`/`await`/`signal`.

Comment: right. plus instead of synchronized ReentrantLock or Condition may be used.

Comment: @VladimirNabokov I have added a short paragraph regarding `Lock` and `Condition` if you're interested. I haven't used the API myself, so I might be missing things, but it should be a start.

Comment: Right, thank you for reminding me about obligatory synchronized. I knew that, but it is so easy to miss...
Your blog is cool BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Waking up from `Object#wait()` or `Condition#await()` means reacquiring the associated lock. **Presumably, `<some condition>` should only be modified when owning the lock.** So if the thread that woke up now owns the lock, no other thread should be able to change the condition to false.